# Benefits of using django-channels instead of not using it

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am working on a chat application, and I am wondering what are the benefits of for example using django-channels instead of making the chat in "raw" django?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

django-channels is an abstraction to make building realtime applications easier. Django itself does not come with baked in websocket features so you could use raw Django and your own web sockets but it will be a lot harder and you will be reinventing lot of what django-channels does.

Comment: Thanks, also why would I want to use redis for the messages instead of sqlite and can I even use for example sqlite for handling messages?

Comment: Sqlite does not allow for concurrent connections. Redis allows for many connections at once. If you have many users you will likely run into limitations with Sqlite. Sqlite is totally suitable for local development though. I don't understand the second part of your question

Comment: When using django-channels, for what exactly is redis needed?

Comment: python has [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock), sqlite is hard disk database, which would run into issue with asynchronous programming. Sqlite is famous for its super fast speed. meanwhile, `redis` stand for remote dictionary server, that is in-memory server, which uses the machine's memory as source of data storage.

Comment: in other words, you cannot build asynchronous real time chat app with sqlite, we must switch to redis instead. Although it is more complicated since we need to plugin docker compose extra.